# Having Trouble in Ubuntu Installation

Tags: 14.04, dell-vostro

I am trying to Install Ubuntu in my Dell Vostro Laptop using a USB drive. However, i am getting the below error msg in the very first place and cant able to Proceed further.
         Could you please help me out on this.

**This Dell Recovery Media can be used to restore the original factory software.
It is recommended you back up all important data before running this tool.**

**Error msg :"This Recovery Media only functions on Dell and Alienware Systems"**

Comment: Is the USB drive you're trying to boot with from Dell? Did it come with the laptop, as a recovery method?

Comment: No it didn't. I have downloaded it from internet and mounted in USB drive by using  www.pendrivelinux.com/downloads/Universal-USB-Installer

Comment: Not the image on the the drive, the physical device itself.

Answer (score 1):

When I tried to repair my ubuntu, I had the same problem. The message I got was "The recovery media tool only functions on Dell and Alienware systems".

Then, I followed the instruction on Dell support website:
http://www.dell.com/support/Article/us/en/19/SLN297060/EN

Then, I changed the boot sequence and boot ubuntu 14.04 from my usb.
It works! :)

My laptop is Dell inspiron 15

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your bootorder in the Bios, USB first. Seems like you are not booting from USB.